# Mitsuba Bidirectional Framework

Tags: rendering, pathtracing, brdf, physically-based

I'm confused by the Mitsuba bidirectional framework for quite a while now, especially by the different `eval` and `connect` functions, as well as the `weight` and `pdf` variables.

So, what is the difference between `PathVertex::eval` and `PathVertex::weight[]`, and `PathVertex::evalPdf` and `PathVertex::pdf[]`.

What are the differences between `PathEdge::evalCached`, `PathEdge::eval*`, `PathEdge::weight[]`, `PathEdge::pdf[]`, etc.

Furthermore, how do the `PathVertex::connect` and `PathEdge::pathConnectAndCollapse` differ?

To make the problem more concrete, let's say I have two vertices, one at the end of an emitter subpath, call it $y_{s-1}$ and one at the end of a sensor subpath, $x_{t-1}$, both surface interactions.

- What is the correct way of connecting these two?
- If I want to calculate $f(y_{s-2} \rightarrow y_{s-1} \rightarrow z_{t-1}) G(y_{s-1} \leftrightarrow x_{t-1}) f(y_{s-1} \rightarrow z_{t-1} \rightarrow z_{t-2})$, what is the correct way of going about this?

Thanks a lot in advance!